Ubuntu 24.04: adding a second language problems
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 2 days ago.  I want to add a second keyboard language and use a mean to switch between the two anytimes.  But the application to do so is not working right.
Sorry I cannot post images as it seams that since this is my first post I am not allowed ...

Each day when I start the Region and language application, it tells me that the language support is not installed completly.  On the first day I installed ubuntu, I had clicked the Installed button so I do not understand why its asking me again each day.  I did it again now and checked the details. I do not remember seeing any errors.

The first time it got installed, by default it had English.  So I clicked French to add it too.  I had not idea it would add the English and French version of a bunch of other English/French (ex: English (Canada), English, English (Austrialia), ...  But the Canadian French is almost at the end of the list and kinda grayed out.  The only ones grayed On are Englisth (Canada) and English.  So when I drag the Canadian French on top the second highlited one (meaning English), nothing happens.  If I drag anyone around and place it somewhere in the non enlighted ones, it sort of work.

I think I read somewhere that after adding a 2nd keyboard language, I would have keyboard icon somewhere on the top right corder.  But I see nothing.


So what is this option bugged?  If so, is there a workaround?  It looks weird typing text in French without the accents ....
Why only the first 2 English one highlighted and not the French ones that got added with my choice?

I found some references in other posts.  Nothing changes in the Region and Language window.  I had to go into settings/keyboard and add French in the Input section.  I than learn the keyboard shortcut to switch between language: windows-key + space.
I noticed another odd behavior.  When I click the Help button on the Region and Language window, the opened Help window is empty.
Seams problem with this 2 language set up has been going on for a very long time ...

I can't reproduce your problem with the help button. When I click it I see four links: 1. Introduction, 2. Language Support, 3. Alternative Language Settings, and 4. Advanced Format Settings. Having said that, please note that this is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. Don't put questions inside your answer.
